# phpMyAdmin - way to edit PHP-serialized data easily?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to make it easy to edit PHP-serialized data in phpMyAdmin without having to resort to some sort of custom patch?  The reason why this is a nuisance is that PHP's serialization format contains the string lengths hard-coded into it, so if you make an edit that changes the length of a string you have to manually recalculate and change the string length too (unlike JSON where there's no length hard-coded)?  WordPress is one big name system that relies on PHP serialization to store data.

Comment: No, there is a feature request about that: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/5950